# Group Theory about direct sum

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $M$ be any Groups and $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$. Let $G/H$ is isomorphic to $M$ then $G$ can be written as a direct sum of $H$ and $M$. Is it is correct? If yes then how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take $G=\mathbb Z, H=2\mathbb Z$, and $M=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, but $G$ is not isomorphic to $H+M$ because $H+M$ has an element of order $2$ and $G$ does not.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct. For instance, take any semi-direct product $G =H \rtimes K$ that is not a direct product; then $G/H  \simeq K$. (In particular, it is easier if $H$ and $K$ are abelian, because in this case $G$ is not abelian.)

Comment: For example, $G=S_3$, with $H$ the unique proper, non-trivial normal subgroup.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $G$ to be cyclic of order $4$ and $H$ to be cyclic of order $2$. Then $K$ is cyclic of order two so $H\oplus K$ is the Klein $4$-group (which is not cyclic of order $4$).